# X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection only working local asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509

I have an ASP.NET C# code using `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection` that is only working locally on my machine just like I want, when the code reaches `SelectFromCollection` it opens a dialog to select with local certificate I want.

But when I publish to the server, It does not asks for my client browser certificate. Tried this on a W2003 IIS6 and W2012 IIS7. What I'm missing on my server configuration?

```
private string LoadCertificateCollection(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation)
{
    X509Store store;
    X509Certificate2Collection collection;
    store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    collection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Escolha um Certificado", "", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The method runs at the server, it will never, ever run on the client. In order to make it at the client side, you'd need a clickonce app deployed from the server to the client.

Comment: In fact I already tested this code creating an Activex, and it works. But only works on IE. And I need to run this on Chrome and Firefox, any tip?

Comment: I just read a little more about ClickOnce, and it seens that it's not possible to interact the app with the web page, and I need this integration.

I'm using x509 to auth users using a local certificate on a smartcard. After the validation, I have to redirect the autenticated user. This webapp is also used to user enrollment and certificate creation (using xenroll at this time, and I'm migrating to certenroll).

Comment: If you only need the auth with a smart card, just turn on ssl in iis with "reqiure client cert". The browser will show up the cert selection dialog on its own. This works for any browser.

Comment: No, I have to read smartcard info and send to server side, not only for auth.

Comment: What info? If using as mentioned, you can access the `HttpRequest`'s `ClientCertificate` property that gives you access to the public part of the client cert. On the other hand, sending client's private key to the server is not possible and should never be. I hope you are not trying to do something that is not possible then.